# Calling a std::function that I have a const reference too

Tags: c++, constants, std-function

I was somewhat confused to find that this code compiles and runs and prints 1 2 3:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::function<int()> counter = [i = 0]() mutable { i++; return i; };
    std::cout << counter() << std::endl;

    const auto& constRef = counter;
    std::cout << constRef() << std::endl;
    std::cout << counter() << std::endl;
}
```

It seems like a violation of const correctness to be able to call a non-const `operator()` of the underlying function when we only hold a `const&` to the `std::function`. Is there something I'm missing?

[godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/BxTyZ6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only overload of [it's call operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/operator()) is

```
std::function<R(Args...)>::operator()( Args... args ) const;
```

It doesn't propagate const to it's target.

Comment: How does that method call the non-const `operator()` of the stored object though?

Comment: Presumably, via pointer. Type erasure generally involves pointers anyway